# How to prove that $GL(V)$ is a Lie-group without a choice of a basis.

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, lie-groups

If we have a general linear group $GL(V)$ of a vector space $V$ (group of automorphisms), we may choose a basis in $V$, then there is an isomorphism (non-canonical) $GL(V) \cong GL(n, \mathbb{F})$ and latter is a manifold of dimension $n \times n$.

**Question:** Is there a way to prove that $GL(V)$ is a Lie-group (or just manifold) **without** a choice of a basis on $V$ (and thus without refering to any matrices whatsoever)?

Comment: It's an open subset of $\mathrm{End}(V)$, so its a submanifold.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat
Then again, how to prove that $End(V)$ is a manifold without choosing a basis on $V$?

Comment: The local homeomorphisms you need to show something is a Lie Group is akin to picking a basis, isnt it?

Comment: You only need to know that $\mathrm{End}(V)$ is finite dimensional.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat
What finite dimensionality gives me? I still need to define topology on $End(V)$ and local homeomorphisms to some $\mathbb{R}^d$ without choosing any basis.

Comment: If you require a homeomorphism with $R^d$ then you will likely need coordinates, but you don't. There is a unique topology on fd real vector spaces that turns them into (Hausdorff) topological vector spaces, and you can define manifolds as spaces that are (Hausdorff, second countable and) locally homeomorphic to f.d. real vector spaces.

Comment: @OlivierBégassat
Yes, I know this theorem about any fd vector space having unique topological structure, but all proofs I've seen rely on some form of a choice of a basis of that vector space.
Is it possible to prove it without any choice at all?

Comment: What local coordinate functions do you propose trying to use?

Comment: @LeeMosher
Well, I don't know. That's what I was actually asking, if it is possible to define any coordinate functions without a choice of basis.

Comment: Do you allow us to use that a vector space with a basis of cardinality 1 is isomorphic to $\mathbb R$?

Comment: I ask because I don't even think I could prove that a 1-dimensional vector space is a manifold without that theorem.

Comment: Also, do you allow us to incorporate the proof of the existence of a basis into our proof? That way we would not be "choosing" a basis.

Comment: @LeeMosher
Yes, axiom of choice and theorem about existence of a basis for any vector space are allowed. Dimensionality of a space can be whatever you wish. The only requirement is that there should be no particular choices of basis during the proof, like it always exists, but we choose none.

Comment: Describing an atlas is exactly choosing a basis on V.

Comment: @JuanDiegoRojas
It is true if $V$ is taken as topological vector space. What if I pick a topology for which operations on $V$ are not continious, maybe then it is possible to construct such an atlas without choosing a basis?

Comment: Thus, you’re asking for a manifold structure in. euclidean space that it is not the usual one. I don’t know if this can happen. However, if one asks about differentiable structures it is well known that 4-dimensional euclidean space admits an exotic differentiable structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not possible, at least not in any remotely natural way.  Giving a manifold structure to an object is very much like choosing a basis: you are defining charts to identify your object (locally) with a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$.  These charts are rarely unique or canonical, just like a basis for a vector space.  So, no matter what, if you want to find a manifold structure, you should expect to have to make some arbitrary choices which are analogous to choosing a basis.  You could probably find some convoluted way to do this by making different sorts of arbitrary choices that are not exactly equivalent to a basis on $V$, but why would you want to do that?

If you wanted to be able to prove something like this without using anything like a basis, you would need to change your definition of a manifold to not specifically reference $\mathbb{R}^n$.  For instance, you could define a manifold as a space that is locally homeomorphic to an open subset of a finite-dimensional topological vector space.  Then you can make $\operatorname{End}(V)$ into a manifold by just enhancing its vector space structure to the unique topological vector space structure (which can be defined without a basis; for instance, you can define it as the finest topology which makes all linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n\to\operatorname{End}(V)$ continuous for all $n$).